# Pandas and TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'bool'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

merged:

```
animal    sampleNum    SampleBreed   Nume    Breed

44          423432        GG        423432    GG  
21          2132          AA        1112      AA   
...
```

First three cols are from base, last two are from newFile. 
I want to create new DF by validate some citerions. I mean:

```
toNewDF = If SampleNum == Nume AND SampleBreed == Breed
```

I wrote that code:

```
merged.where(merged.sampleNum == merged.Nume & merged['SampleBreed'] == merged.breed)
```

but I got an error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'bool'`

If I change `&` to `and` I got:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I'm tried to found any solution, but all threads on SO dealing with different types of problems.

What I'm doing wrong with this code? Can someone explain me it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you just need to wrap it in extra parenthesis, because of operator precedence.

try this:

```py
merged.where((merged.sampleNum == merged.Nume) & (merged['SampleBreed'] == merged.breed))
```

to avoid this ambiguity , I like [using `.eq` instead of `==`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html), like this:

```py
merged.where(merged.sampleNum.eq(merged.Nume) & merged['SampleBreed'].eq(merged.breed))
```

Comment: Damn... I tried it but I got an error too.. now after Ur post everything is fine :D Thanks!nn